# Visual Studio 2012 errors but website project works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web" to maintain a website on our dev server.  (I am not the original developer of this website, but I am the current maintainer.)  When I navigate a browser to the dev website it works.  The site has also been deployed to qa and production servers and it works on those tiers as well.  However, in VS on the dev server I have over 100 errors showing.  With VS in this state the auto-recognize typing doesn’t work and I can’t use any of the debugging features until I can resolve the errors.  Since the website works, it seems like the issue is with VS.

Here is a sample error with some background explanation:

```
Error 1:    Type 'ReportsDashboard' is not defined.
```

The error refers to the file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Reports\Dashboards\Indicators.aspx.vb.
The first few lines of the file are:

```
Imports System.IO
  Partial Class Reports_Dashboards_Indicators
  Inherits ReportsDashboard
    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
… etc…
```

That file is code behind for C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Reports\Dashboards\Indicators.aspx, for which first line is:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Reports/ReportMaster.master" CodeFile="Indicators.aspx.vb" Inherits="Reports_Dashboards_Indicators" EnableViewState="False" %>
…etc…
```

The Inherits line in the code behind file refers to another file:  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Code\ReportsDashboard.vb, for which the first few lines are:

```
Imports System.IO
  Public Class ReportsDashboard
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
…etc…
```

So it looks like the line “Inherits ReportsDashboard” in Indicators.aspx.vb (code behind) is not recognized by VS even though the file is right there in App_Code and everything works when the website is deployed.

Another error occurring frequently in the list is like:

```
Error   21  'TotalLabel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

The error refers to a code behind file (.ascx.vb in this case), but the supposedly undeclared object is right there in the associated .ascx file.

As I mentioned, the website runs.  All the application code, code behind, class definitions, properties, etc do what they are supposed to do.  But for some reason VS throws errors and can’t find the code that is in App_Code.  I can't find any way to explicitly reference code in App_Code, so I assume it is somehow referenced implicitly by .Net.  How can I trouble shoot this problem?  Where should I start looking?

A related question:  I also noticed that some of the code for this project is defined in a separate ClassLibrary project which is included as a reference.  VS doesn’t seem to have any trouble finding the code in there (the class library is first in the build order).  Are those two different ways of doing the same thing, i.e., Compiled code in a separate ClassLibrary project vs uncompiled code in the App_Code folder of the website project?  Would it solve my problem to move the class definitions from App_Code and include them in the compiled ClassLibrary instead? Or what is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are maintaining a web site "project", which is different from all other types of project in Visual Studio. The professional way to do things is to use a web application project (created via File->New Project or Add->New Project), and then to put everything that doesn't directly relate to the web part of the application into separate class libraries. The App_Code nonsense is like sitting at the children's table - you eat the same food, but still...

Comment: OK, thanks for that. I very much appreciate your input, but my delayed response was due to higher priority work. As I understand your suggestion it is to move code from the App_Code folder into separate class libraries, so I will pursue that.  RE: the type of vs project, is there a way to convert a "web site project" to a "web application project"?  I have looked at the vs documentation to some extent, but didn't find it very helpful.

Comment: I believe that if you right-click the project, you'll find "convert to web application". I've never tried it, so don't know how well it works.